# Changing image in Email messes up text alignment in Outlook 2007,2010,2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I have a problem with an email that I have created. I have an email with two tables of the same code, except for an image I changed. When I changed this image the left alignment of the text got messed up in Outlook 2007,2010, and 2013.

This is what it looks like in the email:
[image]

This is the code:
http://codeshare.io/195q4

I have tried everything and need your help!

Comment: How did the text "mess up"? When you changed the image did you restrict the size in HTML or format the image to the same size?

Comment: I used the same width on the image but changed the height.

Answer (score 0):

If you change align="center" on the TD inside each 180px table to align="left" it appears to solve the issue. See below example:

```
        <table width="180" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" valign="top" class="devicewidth paddingleft paddingright">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <img src="http://image.exct.net/lib/fe6615707163057b7617/m/1/Test6.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; font-size: 1px; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 180px; border-color: #000000; margin: 0px; text-align: center;" title="180-image.png" alt="180-image.png" width="180" height="135" mdid="676e2baf-c23e-4da1-bc8c-44a85036dda7" />
                    <p style="text-align: left; font-size: 24px; font-family: Georgia, Arial, Helvetica; color: #52565c; line-height: 30px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    Test 6 
                    </p>
                    <span align="center" style="text-align: left;">
                    <img src="http://image.exct.net/lib/fefc16727d6502/m/1/pixel.gif" height="auto" style="display: block; font-size: 1px; border: none; height: 15px !important;" />
                    </span>
                    <p class="textonly textpaddingbild" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Georgia; color: #52565c; line-height: 20px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: left !important;">
                    Nam ut consequat urna. Duis vitae ante aliquet, luctus nulla id, convallis purus. Suspendisse non euismod tortor.
                    </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Yes it does, but it also makes my images align left in mobile view when I want them to align right. I don't understand how it can work with one of the tables but not the other!

Comment: there are a few validation errors I am running into, especially inside your MSO conditionals (you declare 2 tds on the 3 column rows.).  There is also a huge missing block in your CSS, including stylings with no declared class or element or id on what they should affect. These might be the overlying issues that are causing the weird behavior.